# c# remove alle the same objects from array (without LINQ)

Tags: c#, arrays

I can't remove all the same object from an array in c#. The last doesn't removed.

I add the objects in an array I add them more then one time.

When I try to remove them not all objects are removed.

How can I remove all the same objects.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Cirkel c1 = new Cirkel(2);
    Cirkel c2 = new Cirkel(3);

    Figuur f1 = new Figuur();
    f1.Add(c1);
    f1.Add(c1);
    f1.Add(c2);
    f1.Add(c2);

    f1.VerwijderObject(c2);
}

class Figuur
{
    public Figuur[] _Items = new Figuur[0];
    int count = 0;

    public void Add(Figuur figuur)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        Array.Resize(ref _Items, count);
        _Items[count - 1] = figuur;
    }

    public void VerwijderObject(Figuur figuur)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < _Items.Length; k++)
        {
            if (_Items[k].Equals(figuur))
            {
                for (int i = k; i < (count - 1); i++)
                {
                    _Items[i] = _Items[i + 1];
                }
                count = count - 1;
                Array.Resize(ref _Items, count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `k--;` after `count = count - 1;`. Why don't you use a List<T> instead of handling the array size manipulation manually? This is not efficient also, changing the size of the array with each addition/deletion

Comment: What is expected here? Example: You have Object a and Object b and they are duplicates. Shall a _and_ b removed?

Comment: Oguz Ozgul k--; works thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, Equals does a reference equals comparison. You need to override Equals method in in Cirkel class (you have not provided the code for Cirkel, so don't know what it does).